# Hill Cipher issues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms

I am new to math and have took interest into hill cipher; thus, I have attempted to create my own codes, but have faced several issues. As you may know, hill cipher requires matrix to encrypt and decrypt.

I used mod $32$ for the alphabets where $A=0,\space B=1, ..., Z=25$, where $26$ onwards will be used for punctuation.

However, I would like to make it an exception whereby I will use matrix to decrypt codes BUT WILL NOT use matrix to encrypt.

For example, "help" would be $(7, 4, 11, 15)$. I will encrypt by adding $26$ behind the numbers so I will get another code which can be used to decrypt :
$7 + 26 = 1 \mod 32$ 
$4 + 26 = 30 \mod 32$
$11 + 26 = 5 \mod 32$
$15 + 26 = 9 \mod 32$
My text encrypted will be = $(b,$ punctuation, $f, j)$

This is where problems arise. When I want to start decrypting the text (b, punctuation, f, j) also read as $(1, 30, 5, 9)$ using a matrix, I will be unable to get a constant matrix to decrypt it.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: "As you all know": this is not a good assumption.

Comment: Your code seems similar to a Caesar cipher http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher  ( a shift cipher) Compare with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_cipher

Answer (score 0):

I'm not incredibly familiar with it either but the way I see it the matrix must be thought of as a key; because it is initially multiplied in, you won't be able to get a constant matrix/key/set of numbers to inverse multiply it by if you encrypted your numbers through addition.